# Regular expression issue

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

what is regular expression validator for the textbox which doesnot contains character like "< >" as a string input

Comment: @picnic5u: I beg your pradon?
@Marcelo: +1

Comment: Wow 10 questions asked not accepted a single one. Talk about help vampires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<[^<]+?>
```

This Regex will match "< >" pair.
Add logic to your code to handle situation when this match is found